# sounds storaged in local files in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to find a way to storage a sound for my *Battleship game* in my local file instead of reference its link on internet,
my code referring to the method that triggers this sound is this

```
 @click.prevent="fireSound('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1794&type=mp3')"
```

I did try to do it as if it was an image , i mean

```
 @click.prevent="fireSound('src:'../.../....mp3')"
```

but it didn't work!!!

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Comment: sorry...just vuejs javascript....

Comment: I would recommend to [edit] your question, removing the `java` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know where you put your sound, but in my project I put my sound.mp3 file 
on `assets/music/sound.mp3`

```
playSound(sound) {
  if (sound) {
    const audio = new Audio(require('@/assets/music/sound.mp3'));
    audio.play();
  }
},
```

`@` mean root folder project, Can you share your structure folder to put your file ?